# ASP.NET core read array from applicationsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core

My configuration file looks like:

```
  "app": {
    "Token": "sfasgeagesagasdgdas",
    "Address": "https://localhost",
    "User": "me",
    "Password": "pwd123",
    "Users": [
      {
        "Id": "123456",
        "Username": "me"
      },
      {
        "Id": "234567",
        "Username": "notme"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I can get the token and address by:

```
Configuration["app:Token"];
```

But this approach does not work with json array values. How should I use json array?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934081/reading-a-json-object-from-appsettings-json

Comment: Did you read this post https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited

Comment: or you can  try it https://stackoverflow.com/a/67793854/11298511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, you want to get the Users information.

If you want to get the special user, you could use the following code (change the item index):

```
var user1_id = Configuration["app:Users:1:Id"];
var user1_username = Configuration["app:Users:1:Username"];
```

If you want to get all value of the entire array, you could use the following code:

```
IConfigurationSection myArraySection = Configuration.GetSection("app").GetSection("Users");
var itemArray = myArraySection.AsEnumerable();
```

Besides, if you could also create a `Users` Model base on the Json array:

```
public class Users
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use the following code to get the user data:

```
List<Users> myTestUsers = Configuration.GetSection("app").GetSection("Users").Get<List<Users>>();
```

The result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should read that like this in NET5:

```
var user0_id = config["app:Users:0:Id"];
var user1_id = config["app:Users:1:Id"];
var user0_username = config["app:Users:0:Username"];
```